# How to write a single function for creating dissimilar objects for dissimilar classes based on classname parameter?

Tags: c++

I need to write a function which could create any type object. It receives class name as parameter.
If classes are similar, we can derive all those classes from a single base class and let function return Base *. User of the function could use runtime polymorphism to use the returned object. In this case, function looks like below.

```
Base* createObject(string objName)
{
   if(objName == "D1")
       return new D1;
   else if(objName == "D2")
       return new D2;
   return NULL;
}
```

If the classes are dissimilar, they can't be inherited from a single base class as it would not be proper inheritance. In this case, above function would not be useful.
Lets say i have 3 dissimilar classes like Helicopter, Kitchen and College.
In this case, how does single function could create any kind of object ?
I have one solution like below.
Use a wrapper class to wrap all dissimilar class pointers in an Union.
Then let function create Wrapper object and fill appropriate class pointer based on classname passed to it.
That functin looks like below

```
Wrapper* createObject(string objType)
{
     Wrapper *pWrapper = new Wrapper();
     pWrapper->objectType = objType;
     if(objType == "Helicopter")
     {
         pWrapper->pHelicopter = new Helicopter;
     }
     else if(objType == "Kitchen")
     {
         pWrapper->pKitchen = new Kitchen;
     }
     else if(objType == "College")
     {
         pWrapper->pCollege = new College();
     }
     return pWrapper;
}
```

Wrapper class looks like below.

```
class Wrapper
{
    public:
    string objectType;
    union
    {
        Helicopter *pHelicopter;
        Kitchen *pKitchen;
        College *pCollege;
    };
};
```

Is there any better solution than above ?

Comment: If the types are unrelated how can the user of the class use run time polymorphism to use them? Can you give the bigger picture, what problem are you trying to solve? I feels like you a writing a function that is as unwieldy to use as it is to write.

Comment: @Charles: I wrote, if types are similar, then user of the function can use runtime polymorphism. As the function returns Base*, he can call any virtual functions of derived classes. If types are dissimilar, no way to use runtime polymorphism.

Comment: The problem is that its impossible to really give sensible suggestions here without knowing what you want to achieve. This problem shouldn't occur with proper design.

Comment: I think you should re-think your design. If the objects are completely different, why do you want to create them with the single function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boost already has 2 possible solutions to your problem: [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/variant.html) and [Boost.Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/any.html).

But preferably you should avoid such a design in the first place if you can. If one function returns unrelated objects and you can't refactor to give the types a common interface, you should probably split it into multiple functions.

Answer (score 1):

The wrapper idea is in my eyes a no-go. It it confusing for the user an not a proper use of polymorphism. I would use a create function for each logical group, or, all classes with the same base class. This may lead to several create functions, but in this case you should overthink your design. Another workaround would be to definde a abstract interface class "createable" or so, but I don't like it too. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use 'enums' instead of 'strings', here is a possible solution. It does not avoid single function, but at least gets rid of that huge if-else

```
enum X {HELI, SHIP, BUS, TRAIN, COLLEGE, KITCHEN};

struct Heli{
};

struct College{
};
....
template<X x> struct Creator{
};

template<> struct Creator<HELI>{
   Heli *Create(){return new Heli();}
};

template<> struct Creator<COLLEGE>{
   College *Create(){return new College();}
};

int main(){
   Heli *ph = Creator<HELI>().Create();
   College *pc = Creator<COLLEGE>().Create();
   delete ph;
   delete pc;
}
```